# Calling Access VBA function from Excel error 2517

Tags: vba

I searched the answers for a solution and didn't see one which fit what I was trying to do so I am posting.

I have a compensation spreadsheet which calls and access database function.  Here is the excel code:

```
Option Explicit

    Public appAccess As Access.Application

    Private Sub AutoComp(WritingLevel)
        If appAccess Is Nothing Then
            Set appAccess = New Access.Application
            With appAccess
                .OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\MyPath\Compensation.accdb"
                .Visible = False
                Debug.Print .Run("AutoComm", WritingLevel)
            End With
        End If
    End Sub
```

The debug statement generates Run-time error 2517 cannot find the procedure 'AutoComm.'  Here is AutoComm in the database:

```
Public Function AutoComm(WritingRepContract As String) As Single
    If ValidRepTitle(WritingRepContract) Then
        AutoComp = DLookup("[1st_Year]", "tblAuto_Comm", "[Title] ='" & WritingRepContract & "'")
    End If
End Function
```

Even if I only have AutoComm pop up a msgbox it never gets that far.  It acts like it can't find the Access code.  Your help is very appreciated.

Comment: Not that familiar with Access, but you could try `Debug.Print .Run("ModuleName.AutoComm", WritingLevel)`

Comment: Also, make sure that *AutoComm* is in a *Standard Module* (not a Class, Form, or Report Module) and that there is **not** an *Option Private Module* statement at the top of said Standard Module.

Comment: What happens if you do: `appAccess.Modules.Application.Run "AutoComm"` or `appAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro "AutoComm"` ?

Comment: There is a typo in your `AutoComm` function - you're assigning the return value to `AutoComp`

Comment: Also: your test for `If appAccess Is Nothing Then` is wrapped around your entire `AutoComp` code, so once you've instantiated an instance of Access and assigned it to `appAccess` and subsequent calls to the Sub will do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

Excel:

```
Option Explicit

Public appAccess As Access.Application

Private Sub AutoComp()

    If appAccess Is Nothing Then
        Set appAccess = New Access.Application
        With appAccess
            .Visible = False
            .OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\_Stuff\test.accdb"
        End With
    End If

    With appAccess
        Debug.Print "Result:" & .Run("AutoComm", "TestInput")
    End With

End Sub
```

Access (in a standard module):

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function AutoComm(WritingRepContract As String) As String
    AutoComm = "WritingRepContract = " & WritingRepContract
End Function
```

Comment: I must be missing something basic.  I tried your code in my spreadsheet and database and it did not work.  Then I tried your code in a new spreadsheet and new database and it did not work. The spreadsheet code is in Sheet1 and the db code is in modules in a module named Comp.  Do I have them in the correct locations?

Comment: I got it working.  I am not certain what I did, but I think it had to do with moving some of the code from 'ThisWorkbook' to Sheet1.  Tim, your code help me streamline the troubleshooting and resolve the problem.  Pieter & Djikay I have not tried your solutions yet, but will once I break free.  I appreciate everyone's input - you folks make a HUGE difference!  Thx!